Prove that $\mathop{\sum }\limits_{{n = 1}}^{\infty }\frac{{\left( -1\right) }^{\left\lbrack \sqrt{n}\right\rbrack }}{n}{z}^{n}$ converges on $|z|=1$

Prove that $\mathop{\sum }\limits_{{n = 1}}^{\infty }\frac{{\left( -1\right) }^{\left\lbrack  \sqrt{n}\right\rbrack  }}{n}{z}^{n}$ converges on $|z|=1$, but does not converge absolutely on $|z|=1$.

If we just consider the real case, we may consider alternating series, but for complex ones, I feel frustrated, since I do not have any method at the hand.

To avoid the question being downvoted, I strongly encourage you to reformulate the question in such a way that it is clear where you get stumbled and no ambiguity may be involved. As of now, the post appears unclear since there's no question! Additionally, if you use unusual notation, clarify what it means.

Just to be clear: that is the floor of sqrt(n), correct?

@AdamRubinson Yes, it is.

Ok. I tried to use Dirichlet's Test/Abel's test, but I don't think they help.

Let $z=e^{i\theta},\theta\in[0,2\pi]$,
For $\theta=0$ and $2\pi$，we need to prove that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{[\sqrt n]}}{n}$$
is convergent which can be refered $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{[\sqrt n]}}{n}$.
For $\theta\in(0,2\pi)$, we use the following $\bf{Dirichlet-Abel\ test}$:Dirichlet-Abel


If the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n,\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ satisfy the following conditions:
(1) $\left\{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\right\}$ is bounded;
(2) $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}b_n=0;$
(3) $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty|b_n-b_{n+1}|$ is convergent,
then the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n$ is convergent.


Let $a_n=z^n$ and $b_n=\frac{(-1)^{[\sqrt n]}}{n}$,
then we have
$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\right|=\left|\frac{z(1-z^n)}{1-z}\right|
\leq\frac{2}{1-|z|},\quad z=e^{i\theta},\theta\in(0,2\pi);$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=0,\quad \sum_{n=1}^\infty|b_n-b_{n+1}|
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left|\frac{(-1)^{[\sqrt n]}}{n}-\frac{(-1)^{[\sqrt {n+1}]}}{n+1}\right|=\frac{\pi^2}{3}-1<\infty.$$
So, by Dirichlet-Abel test, we know that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{[\sqrt n]}}{n}z^n$$
is convergent when $z=e^{i\theta}$ and  $\theta\in(0,2\pi)$.
The serie does not converge absolutely on $|z|=1$ is easy to get.


By-product:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left|\frac{(-1)^{[\sqrt n]}}{n}-\frac{(-1)^{[\sqrt {n+1}]}}{n+1}\right|=\frac{\pi^2}{3}-1<\infty,$$


Proof:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left|\frac{(-1)^{[\sqrt n]}}{n}-\frac{(-1)^{[\sqrt {n+1}]}}{n+1}\right|
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=n^2}^{(n+1)^2-1}\left|\frac{(-1)^{[\sqrt k]}}{k}-\frac{(-1)^{[\sqrt {k+1}]}}{k+1}\right|$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=n^2}^{(n+1)^2-2}\frac1{k(k+1)}+\frac1{(n+1)^2-1}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)=\frac{\pi^2}{3}-1=2.89868\cdots.$$

Why give me a downvote? Please point out !

No absolute convergence: Compare with the harmonic series:   $$\sum_n\mid\frac {(-1)^{\lfloor \sqrt n\rfloor}}nz^n\mid=\sum_n\frac 1n,$$ for  $\mid z\mid=1.$
For the radius of convergence,  try Cauchy-Hadamard: $$r=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac 1{\mid\frac {(-1)^{\lfloor \sqrt n\rfloor}}n\mid^{\frac1n}}=1,$$  because $n^{\frac 1n}\to1.$
Convergence for $\mid z\mid=1$ is still up in the air. But by comparison with $$\sum\frac {z^n}n,$$ which is the Taylor series for $-\log(1-z),$ it converges on $\mid z\mid=1, z\neq1.$
Finally to do $z=1,$ the hint in the comments allows you to use the Leibniz test.
